# how do you sort group of arrays that are paired to each other?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

how do you sort group of arrays that are paired to each other?
for example is that if you have an array of student numbers and student names. how can i make student names adjust too. when you sort it by student number?

example output of what i wanted to be:

```
unsorted:
ID numbers     name     course
5             jomar     IT
3             karen     CS

sorted (by ID numbers)
ID numbers     name     course
3             karen     CS
5             jomar     IT
```

I've tried to use TreeMap but there's this problem that if the value of ID numbers are the same, it will overwrite the other and it will print like this:

```
sorted (by ID numbers)
ID numbers     name     course
3             karen     CS
```

in reply to Stultuske 
i tried to use 1 array that contains id num, name, course.
its like this:

```
 for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
     String [][] storeAllArray = {{array[i]},{array2[i]},{array3[i]}};
     System.out.println(storeAllArray[0][0] + " " 
                      + storeAllArray[1][0] + " "
                      + storeAllArray[2][0]);
 }
```

Comment: you shouldn't have such arrays. you should have one array with instances of student, which have: a number, a name, a course they follow....

Comment: @Stultuske then how will you sort it? i did that. but i don't know how to sort it. my array is like this: 

for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
String [][] storeAllArray = {{array[i]},{array2[i]},{array3[i]}};
System.out.println(storeAllArray[0][0]+" "+storeAllArray[1][0]+" "+storeAllArray[2][0]);

Comment: Please don't dump code in a comment.  Just edit your original post.

Comment: take a look at this: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: Please implement either the `java.lang.Comparable<Object>` or `java.util.Comparator<Object>` interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Student implements Comparable {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String course;

    public Student(int pid, int pname, int pcourse) {
        id = pid;
        name = pname;
        course = pcourse;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return new Integer(id).compareTo(new Integer(((Student)o).getID()));
    }

    public int getID() { return id; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getCourse() { return course; }
}
```

At that point, you just make an ArrayList (Or whatever collection you like) of Students, and call `Collections.sort(~initialized ArrayList~);`

Answer (score 0):

If you had a `Collection<Student>`, you'd sort it like this:

```
Collections.sort(studentList,new Comparator<Student>() { 
  int compareTo(Student s1, Student s2) { 
     return s1.getSomeField().compareTo(s2.getSomeField());
  )
});
```

Basically you pass a `Comparator` (generated inline here) to `Collections.sort()`

I'd highly recommend against the parallel array version since it's really avoiding the OO nature of Java.

But if you *REALLY* want to do it, you'd have to have a third array that is just the indexes from 1 to number of elements in your array, then you'd have to use a parallel index array and sort it using Arrays.sort() with a Comparator that compares your parallel array's values (instead of the index array) and then you iterator over the sorted index array and print out the elements that match the index of the other array... Really much easier to do it correctly as above.

Answer (score 0):

Part 1: Define your Comparator as following:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Object[]> {

    @Override
    public int compare( Object[] o1, Object[] o2 ) {
        if ( (int) o1[0] > (int) o2[0] )
            return 1;
        else if ( !((int) o1[0] > (int) o2[0]) )
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

}
```

Part 2: And then follow my example code below in your `main` class:

```
public class MyComparatorTest {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {


    List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

    Object[] o = new Object[3];
    o[0] = 2;
    o[1] = "TWO";
    o[2] = "RR";
    list.add(o);

    o = new Object[3];
    o[0] = 3;
    o[1] = "THREE";
    o[2] = "GG";
    list.add(o);

    o = new Object[3];
    o[0] = 1;
    o[1] = "ONE";
    o[2] = "TT";
    list.add(o);

    // This sorts your list
    Collections.sort(list, new MyComparator());

    // The following loop is only to show you the sorted list content. 
    for (Object[] obj : list) {
        for (Object obj2 : obj) {
            System.out.print(" " + obj2);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    }

}
```

Sample output is:

```
 1 ONE TT
 2 TWO RR
 3 THREE GG
```

Comment: i have a problem. i don't have a fix value of my array. it depends on what the user input including how many times they want to input. and the other thing is that based on your coding, i'll only need one array/object to hold my student id, name, and course. it'll look like this:


        Object[] o = { arrayStudent[i] };

i can't create 2nd object anymore because all the user inputted  will go into arrayStudent. what if there's 10 input? will i need 10 objects to make it compare? or maybe i'm just thinking it wrong. @Mohammad

Comment: Yes. you're thinking wrong. You could just use ONE reference and create an object over and over (create a for-loop or something. My code is just an example). I've modified the code to show you what I mean. In addition, for this situation, you need to understand what a `Comparator` class does.

Comment: so i should have an array like this: 
String arrayALL [][]=new String[3][i];
i will place student id to [0][i] then i will place name to [1][i] and course to [2][i]
and then do it like this:

Object[] o = new Object[3];
    o[0] = arrayALL[0][i];
    o[1] = arrayALL[1][i];
    o[2] = arrayALL[2][i];
    list.add(o);

Collections.sort(list, new MyComparator());

Comment: how about the comparator. it indicates an object o2 but i don't have an object 2. @Mohammad